# Cross referenced tables from multi-dimensional arrays php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How do it turn a multidimensional array like:

```
$fruits['apples']['blue'] = 24;
$fruits['bananas']['blue'] = 12;
$fruits['apple']['red'] = 34;
$fruits['gooseberries']['orange'] = 4;
$fruits['oranges']['red'] = 12;
```

into a cross referenced table like:

[alt text http://1updesign.org/uploads/p24.png](http://1updesign.org/uploads/p24.png)

Comment: Hard to understand. Do you want to output your PHP array as an HTML table (in that case, just loop), or do you try to create something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$cols = array('blue', 'red', 'orange');
echo '<table>';
echo '<thead><tr><td></td><th scope="col">' . implode('</th><th scope="col">', $cols) . '</th></tr></thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
foreach($fruits as $label => $row)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th scope="row">' . $label . '</th>';
    foreach($cols as $k)
    {
      echo '<td>' . (isset($row[$k]) ? $row[$k] : 0) . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

You’ll want some HTML escaping and such, but that’s the gist of it.

Comment: instead of writing $cols = array('blue', 'red', 'orange');, the code should know the colors array as well. This means one extra foreach to get the colors first.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is bad designed. How should one know, that `apples` is the same as `apple`. Your array should be constructed this way:

```
$fruits['apples']['blue'] = 24;
$fruits['apples']['read'] = 24;
$fruits['bananas']['blue'] = 12;
$fruits['gooseberries']['orange'] = 4;
$fruits['oranges']['red'] = 12;
```

Then iterating is easy. The first level of the array are the rows. So:

```
<?php
$column_head = array();
foreach($fruits as $key => $value) {
   $column_head = array_merge($column_head, array_keys($value));
}

$column_head = array_unique($column_head);
print_r($column_head);

?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <?php foreach($column_head as $head): ?>
            <th><?php echo $head; ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($fruits as $fruit => $amount): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fruit ?></td>
        <?php foreach($column_head as $head): ?>
            <td><?php echo isset($amount[$head]) ? $amount[$head] : 0 ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

This generates which columns to use on fly, but it can be hardcoded which might be easier. As the code uses a lot loops it might be not that efficient...